# How do I ensure strings within a nested object refer to one of the objects keys

Tags: typescript, types

How do I make typescript restrict a string type to only being keys within the same object? A simplified example is below.. I've tried a variety of `K extends string` type logic but am stumped.

```js
{
  players: {
    uniquePlayerId1: {
       isTargeting: 'uniquePlayerId2' // should only be able to be `uniquePlayerId1` or `uniquePLayerId2` or any other keys of the `players` object
    },
    uniquePlayerId2: {
      isTargeting: 'uniquePlayerId1', // should only be able to be `uniquePlayerId1` or `uniquePLayerId2` or any other keys of the `players` object
    },
  }
}
```

My use case is I'm building a game - the example is simplified, but essentially each player can target another player - indicated by the value of `isTargeting` - either a string, which I'd like to enforce being a one of the keys of the object, e.g. `uniqueId1` or `uniqueId2` in the example, or null - they aren't targeting anyone.

Comment: There is no specific type that meets this need; you could use a generic type to act as a constraint with a helper function.  I'd show you how, but can you make this a [mre] first with no typos (`isTargeting` or `isTargetting`?) and enough use case info to understand the requirements (you don't care if the first one is a random `string` but the second one needs to be one of the top-level keys? Can you show examples of good and bad inputs?)

Comment: I still see `null | string` in your code comment but that's not right, is it?  Both of them need to be `null | "uniqueId1" | "uniqueId2"`, right?

Comment: ah yeah good point - but I'll just remove the nulls from the question as that's not what's important to it

Comment: So does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WKVgDm) meet your needs? If so I can write up an answer when I get a chance. If not, could you tell me what I'm missing (preferably with code examples that show what goes wrong)?

Comment: yes this works thank you! I may solve the actual problem in a different way, but this is great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no *specific* type in TypeScript that works this way; if you statically knew the list of keys `K` in `players`, (say `"uniquePlayerId1" | "uniquePlayerId2"`)for any particular choice of keys in `players`, then you could define a specific type `PlayersType<K>` in terms of it like

```
type PlayersType<K extends string> =
  { players: Record<K, { isTargeting: K }> }
```

But since you don't know `K` in advance, you want to define `SomePayersType` which is equal to `PlayersType<K>` for *some* `K`.  This sort of type is called an [*existentially quantified* generic type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_system#Existential_types) and, although it's been requested (see [microsoft/TypeScript#14466](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14466)), TypeScript does not directly support such types.  Like most languages with generics, TypeScript only has *universally quantified* generic types.  If we had existentially quantified generics you might be able to say:

```
// not valid TypeScript, don't try this:
type SomePlayersType = <exists K extends string> PlayersType<K>
```

But for now you can't.  There are ways to emulate existential types with universal types but they are cumbersome and not necessarily warranted for your use case.

---

Instead, what you could do is take the `PlayersType<K>` and make a generic helper identity function which infers `K` for you from the passed-in value.  It might look like this:

```
const asPlayers = <K extends string>(
  obj: PlayersType<K>
) => obj;
```

But unfortunately this doesn't quite work how you want; the compiler actually infers `K` from the `isTargeting` values and not from the keys of `players`, meaning that it will reject valid arguments:

```
const players = asPlayers({
  players: {
    uniquePlayerId1: {
      isTargeting: 'uniquePlayerId2' // error?!
    },
    uniquePlayerId2: {
      isTargeting: 'uniquePlayerId2'
    },
  }
})
```

We'd like to tell the compiler not to infer `K` from `isTargeting`; that is, make `isTargeting` a *non-inferential type parameter usage* of `K`, as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#14829](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/14829).  There are different ways to get such behavior; in this case we can just add a new type parameter `L` which is [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to `K`, and use `K` for the keys and `L` for `isTargeting`:

```
const asPlayers = <K extends string, L extends K>(
  obj: { players: Record<K, { isTargeting: L }> }
): PlayersType<K> => obj;
```

Now let's use it:

```
const players = asPlayers({
  players: {
    uniquePlayerId1: {
      isTargeting: 'uniquePlayerId2'
    },
    uniquePlayerId2: {
      isTargeting: 'uniquePlayerId1'
    },
  }
})
/* const players: PlayersType<"uniquePlayerId1" | "uniquePlayerId2"> */
```

That looks good; the compiler is inferring that `players` is of type `PlayersTaype<"uniquePlayerId1" | "uniquePlayerId2">`.  Let's see what happens if we pass in something bad:

```
const badPlayers = asPlayers({
  players: {
    uniquePlayerId1: {
      isTargeting: "oopsie" // error
      // Type '"oopsie"' is not assignable to 
      // type '"uniquePlayerId1" | "uniquePlayerId2"'
    },
    uniquePlayerId2: {
      isTargeting: 'uniquePlayerId1'
    }
  }
})
```

Here we see the desired compiler error; since there is no key named `"oopsie"`, the `isTargeting` property cannot be named `"oopsie"`.

So there you go.  Instead of having a specific `SomePlayersType` type, you have a `PlayersType<K>` type where you infer `K` from the value.  This is sort of "half-way" to an existential type, and might be good enough for your needs.  You might find yourself carrying around this extra type parameter, so maybe you want to use something easier like `PlayersType<string>` inside code you control, and only enforce the inference of `K` for less trusted code:

```
function publicFacingCode<K extends string>(players: PlayersType<K>) {
  innerLibraryCode(players);
}

function innerLibraryCode(players: PlayersType<string>) {

}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.4#code/C4TwDgpgBACgNgQxBATgZwCrggHgNJQQAewEAdgCZpRrAoCWZA5gHxQC8AsAFBRQDeUMImToAXFABKEAMYB7FBXwAaAVHqYEKJhGCMmEggF82RnjwD0AKh6hIUAMpyAthHhJUmbByg5iG4GoCYlJKaloGZhZ+Hj5hD3EpWQUlPFVBDQwtHT1mQygTHjNuKwtzbjtoJ1d3US97dl9JVRYAChkAIwl8QhJyKho6fTawCVrPLEh8FgBKDjZJOfYFgG5ysgRXNDAEGWgAeTkwahjeKHkyWigENHH0Hx6Q-vChqNbYvig5DoArMZEJthph8lmxvj81twPhcrvE6j4bnc0K1Tp8hADEqi0VAAK5kegARxxbgxAEkKABGCRY7HqTTaXT6CQAcjxhOJd3JACZmVALBZCCgUAoAPwAQg+aKMyklnzZRJJCW51NlaMy2UZeSgrPxCs5FB5qoKMrOfGKZpm5T4MOAUA6CAoSIRtwxyJp6ISaBVprluo5ZMp3tpfHVDNyBigACI5Ec0PQIJG+QLUMKUEbpUb5f6lQag8HQzkmdqs4rROSKcz07LzQVLdxijwbdcXZ6HsE+mFBpEmKoADK9UIDPBtD7g6keuoSaTyRQqNQFzUR-smAo8Gb-T2TXDD+ZfX6QxtyS62uGeZ1IlEfU+Y2Ul-VUgRGhfhll3gOGn0Zn1vnNcvNq+lCy1HV2VLVBy0rT8TTNIo62sc4j1hV0NzqLccEjH8y0pRMAB8o0w8CDUjNhSnKJt7UdV1z1dS8zmvL1H2-P0wJQct-0+Z8i2jWN40TflBVTI1+K3bVuOOXjeQ0KAyDkW0bjjJgNg6OBoGAOQoCEgVKlEgjWOwqA8Iw5j9S5SNIKlaDfVAkz2JDQDF1fYyAwrasPmKIw63KAAzPEZD0I8hBxZT6BkAAxXZ9AAYTkChtwHZ4u2GVp6JQwEpmHOYsUYMhUF7egOhQLQQGi2LktdGZIQbKFuB8sg-PoALsty-LCpQYqYogMrPVS9A0IiYZMvKIwgA)